# Facing issues during conversion of a React app into Preact

Tags: reactjs, preact

I am trying to add a create-react-app project into a preact-app. I was using the react-vis-network library : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-vis-network  in my react project and everything was working fine. Now I have added the same dependency in the preact project and now when I run my preact project, I get the below error in this library.

[image]

Can anyone please suggest me what changes needs to be done in my preact project.